# Clickable link in mailapp script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, html-email

I'm trying to put a clickable link into an email using Mailapp.SendEmail. I've broken up the link into pieces to avoid concatenation confusion, based on some other answers I've read.  However, the html still shows up as text in the email.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var responses = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]
  var lastContact = responses.getRange(1,13).getValue();
  var tag1 = '<a href="'
  var link = "docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfODcXSXa_xt1E78MM9uekSlOoCXwdy-EvVryY4RP0P0fZ_A/viewform"
  var tag2 = '"> our registration page  </a>';  
  var full = tag1+link+tag2

  Logger.log(tag1+link+tag2)
  if(responses.getLastRow()-1 > lastContact){
    for(var i = lastContact+1; i<=responses.getLastRow()-1; i++){
       MailApp.sendEmail(responses.getRange(i,4).getValue(), "Registration Confirmed: South and Southeast Queens Rising", "Hello, "+ responses.getRange(i,2).getValue() +" "+responses.getRange(i,3).getValue() + ",\n\n" 
                     + "Thank you for registering for our event  We will be sending a detailed program for this exciting event very shortly. \n\n"
                     + "We encourage you to attend the event with colleagues.  To do so, please return to " + full + " to list employees, associates, and partners who will join you on September 12, 2017."
                     + "We look forward to meeting you soon!  \n\n"
                     + "Thank you, \n"
                     + "Signature"
                    )
}
responses.getRange(1,13).setValue(responses.getLastRow()-1)
```

}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) `sendEmail()` method you can specify that for devices that allow html - to use the html content in the `htmlBody` option/advanced parameter.

```
function myFunction() {
  ...
  var html_link = "<a href='docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfODcXSXa_xt1E78MM9uekSlOoCXwdy-EvVryY4RP0P0fZ_A/viewform'> our registration page  </a>";

  var html_body = "Hello, "+ responses.getRange(i,2).getValue() +" "+responses.getRange(i,3).getValue() + ",<br><br>" 
                 + "Thank you for registering for our event  We will be sending a detailed program for this exciting event very shortly. <br><br>"
                 + "We encourage you to attend the event with colleagues.  To do so, please return to " + html_link + " to list employees, associates, and partners who will join you on September 12, 2017."
                 + "We look forward to meeting you soon!  <br><br>"
                 + "Thank you, <br>"
                 + "Signature"
  ...

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: responses.getRange(i,4).getValue(),
    subject: "Registration Confirmed: South and Southeast Queens Rising",
    body: "Can add a Plain Text version of the email body here for email apps that dont do html",
    htmlBody: html_body
  });

  ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for Outlook but not for gmail, which is still displaying the html text.  I know that gmail does html and I'm hesitant to have a plain text version, since the link is rather important.

Comment: Updated the code with the link as one string and tested with Gmail. This should work - not sure why the `string` link was in 3 parts..is it a requirement?

Comment: What does `responses.getRange(i,2).getValue()` contain? Does it have HTML tags? If so, I believe they will need to be wrapped in [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) `createHtmlOutput()` - not 100% on this

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much!

To answer your questions: the tag was broken up because I read that that might help in this thread -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465808/mailapp-sendemail-htmlbody-clickable-dynamic-link 
responses.getRange(i,2).getValue() contains the email address of each respondent, that isn't causing a problem.