# Hyperlinking specific text in email mesage sent from google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I want to add a hyperlink to a specific portion of text in the email message this line of code is referencing:
`var message = row[2]; // Third column`?

I've tried this suggestion `<p> Please check out my <a href=https://example.com>site</a>` but I can't figure out how to insert it in the variable for the `htmlbody`. I've also tried hardcoding the actual email message in the script but keep receiving errors.

Full code:

````
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1000; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:D1000
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var subject = row[1]; // Second column
    var message = row[2]; // Third column
    var emailSent = row[3]; // Fourth column
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {
        htmlBody: message.replace(/\n/g,'<br>')});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `I want to add a hyperlink to a specific portion of text in the email message this line of code is referencing: var message = row[2]; // Third column?`. You want to put the text value to Spreadsheet and retrieve the value? Or you want to replace the value of `row[2]` after the values were retrieved from Spreadsheet?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465808/mailapp-sendemail-htmlbody-clickable-dynamic-link

Comment: @JeffRush I think, but I'm not sure how to add what you suggested to my script. Could you please show me what portion of your suggestion I should include, and where in my script I should place it?

Comment: @MattStapleton take a look on my answer, it contains basic example of how to send an html email with apps script, you can adapt this example to your case

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Use `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', options)`

Take a look on **options**: [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

## Step by step guide:

1. Fill your sheet with this data:
   [image]
2. Open Apps Script and put this code

```
function sendEmail() {

  let data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:C1").getValues()
  
  let emailAddress = data[0][0]; 
  let subject = data[0][1]; 
  let message = data[0][2];

  let options = {
    htmlBody: `<a href="https://google.com">${message}</a>`
  }
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', options);

}
```

3. Run your code and check your inbox. You will see something like this

[image]